# Error en la cabecera - Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Tags: php, html

Este es el error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\newop\template\header.php:80) in C:\xampp\htdocs\newop\mainindex.php on line 16

La línea 80 del header es esta (es una sola línea, solo que descompactada):

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 device-select">
    <a href="budget.php?device=2">
        <img class="full-width" src="res/images/device2.jpg">
        </img>
    </a>
    <center class="popular-devices">
<?php echo $lang['header_dropdown_string_2'];?>
    </center>
</div>
```

... y este el código:

```html
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])){ header("Location: index.php"); }
?>
<html>
  <body>
<?php
  include("template/head.php");
  include("template/header.php");
  include ("db_files/db.php");
  $usermail = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_SESSION['user']);
  $strSQL = "SELECT nivel FROM usuarios where email ='$usermail'";
  $query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    if ($result['nivel'] == 1 || $result['nivel'] == 2){
    header("location: userlist:php");
  }
  
}
  $state = array(
    1 => $lang['state_name_string_1'],
    2 => $lang['state_name_string_2'],
    3 => $lang['state_name_string_3'],
    4 => $lang['state_name_string_4'],
  );
?>
  <div class="content container">
    <div class="row no-margin no-padding">
      <div class="col-md-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <div class="mainuserimage">
          <img class="full-width" src="res/images/users/user1.png"/>
        </div>
        <div>
<?php
            $strSQL = "SELECT nombre, email, telefono FROM usuarios where email ='$usermail'";
            $query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
            while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
              echo "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></i> ".$result['nombre']."<br>";
              echo "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></i> ".$result['email']."<br>";
              echo "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-earphone'></i> ".$result['telefono']."<br>";
            }
?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12">
      <h3 class="main-title"><?php echo $lang['mainindex_string_1']; ?></h3><br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
            <p><?php echo $lang['mainindex_string_2']; ?></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
            <p><?php echo $lang['mainindex_string_3']; ?></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
            <p><?php echo $lang['mainindex_string_4']; ?></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <p><?php echo $lang['mainindex_string_5']; ?></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
            <p><?php echo $lang['mainindex_string_6']; ?></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <p><?php echo $lang['mainindex_string_7']; ?></p>
          </div>
<?php
            $strSQL = "SELECT id, marca, modelo, imei, descripcion_problema, problem, problem2, problem2_namees, estado, fecha_creacion FROM tickets, problem2 WHERE tickets.email = '$usermail' AND tickets.problem2 = problem2.problem2_id";
            $query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
            while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ ?>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <p><a href="repairdetail.php?id=<?php echo $result['id']; ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i></a>  <?php echo $result['marca']; ?></p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <p><?php echo $result['modelo']; ?></p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <p><?php echo $result['imei']; ?></p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <p><?php echo $result['problem2_namees']; ?></p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-3">
                <p><?php echo $state[$result['estado']]; ?></p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <p><?php echo $result['fecha_creacion']; ?></p>
              </div>
<?php
            }
?>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
  include("template/footer.php");
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Además..error aparte: `include("template/head.php");` lo tienes en el body

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mueve el bloque:

```
include ("db_files/db.php");
$usermail = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_SESSION['user']);
$strSQL = "SELECT nivel FROM usuarios where email ='$usermail'";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    if ($result['nivel'] == 1 || $result['nivel'] == 2){
        header("location: userlist.php"); //<= Error: userlist:php !!!
    }
}
```

antes de:

```
<html>
...
```

> Las funciones PHP que envían o modifican las cabeceras HTTP se deben
>   ejecutar antes de que se haya empezado a enviar la página solicitada
>   al usuario.

**Información adicional sobre el error:** `- headers already sent`

Un mensaje `HTTP` consta de una cabecera - `Header` y un cuerpo -`Body` que son enviados en este orden al cliente - `Client`. En el momento que se envía el `Body` no se puede enviar ya más el `Header`.

Si intentas entonces de llamar la función `header()` después que se haya mandado `HTML`, te va ha producir el famoso error: `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent`.

No sólo la función [header()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) modifica el `Header` si no también las siguientes funciones:

- [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.setcookie.php)
- [setrawcookie()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.setrawcookie.php)
- [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php)
- [session_regenerate_id()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-regenerate-id.php)
- [header_remove()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header-remove.php)

Otros ejemplos cuales producen también error antes de enviar el `Header`:

- Espacios antes de abrir `_<?php`
- Espacios después de cerrar `?>_`
- Usar [UTF-8 con BOM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_orden_de_bytes)
- Mostrar/añadir información/contenido o mensajes de error:
  `HTML`, `echo`, `print`, `var_dump()`....etc

Ejemplos de códigos erróneos:

```
<?php
echo "Foo Bar"; // Mostrar contenido echo
setcookie("Foo", "Bar");
```

---

```
 <?php // Espacio antes del "<?php"
session_start();
?>
```

---

```
<html> <!-- Mostrando contenido HTML -->
<head>
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

Comment: Esta es la respuesta correcta, a mi me ha pasado alguna vez y es por eso mismo

Comment: Muy útil pregunta y muy útil respuesta. +1 !!

Answer (score 4):

El error se produce porque estás enviando la salida html antes de modificar el header, con lo cual, las cabeceras por defecto ya han sido enviadas.

Puedes solucionarlo moviendo el bloque de html tras el comando header. O también usando la función `ob_start()` en las primeras líneas de código. Eso iniciará la caché del búfer de salida y las cabeceras no se enviarán hasta finalizar el script.