# ¿Como evitar reenvío del formulario?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Teniendo esto:

```html
<footer>
  <div class="row no-margin no-padding">
    <div class="col-md-4  col-xs-6 oneplayer">
    <br>
      <a class="logo navbar-brand no-margin no-padding" href="index.php"><img class="logo-img" src="res/images/oneplayer_logo.png"></img></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
      <div class="row no-margin no-padding">
        <div class="col-md-4 footer-links-container">
          <a href="aboutus.php" class="header-links"><?php echo $lang['footer_string_1']; ?></a><br><br>
          <a href="index.php#contact" class="header-links"><?php echo $lang['footer_string_4']; ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 footer-links-container">
          <a href="politica_privacidad.php" class="header-links"><?php echo $lang['footer_string_2']; ?></a><br><br>
          <a href="condiciones.php" class="header-links"><?php echo $lang['footer_string_3']; ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 footer-links-container">
          <form action="" method="post">
            <p class="footer-contact-info"><?php echo $lang['footer_string_5']; ?></p>
            <input type="email" class="my-form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['footer_string_6']; ?>" name="newsemail" /> <button class="newsletter-button"><?php echo $lang['footer_string_7'];?></button><br> <br>
          </form>
          <?php
            if (isset ($_POST['newsemail'])){
              include("db_files/db.php");
              $newsemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['newsemail']);
              $strSQL = "INSERT INTO newsletter (`email`) VALUES ( '$newsemail')";
              $query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
              unset($_POST['newsemail']);
            }
          ?>
          <p class="footer-contact-info"> 999 999 999
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Quiero que después de hacer el `insert`, la variable `$_POST['newsemail']` se elimine, ya que al recargar la página vuelve a intentar hacer el `insert`.

También me valdría hacer esto de alguna otra manera pero no se me ocurre, ya que este formulario está en el `footer` de la página (el `footer` está en un archivo a parte "template/footer.php")

¿Qué opciones tengo para hacer algo así?

esto es lo que quiero evitar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He cambiado el titulo de la pregunta

Comment: He eliminado mi respuesta ya que la función unset() es lo que buscas como te han comentado en las otras dos respuestas. Entendí mal tu pregunta.

Comment: Mostrar el mapa no es algo necesrio

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hay una forma que se llama [PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) Pattern](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), que impide enviar formularios por duplicado.

Es decir, que cuando se envia el formulario mediante **POST** tienes que **REDIRECCIONAR** mediante la función [header()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php), a una página por ejemplo `enviado.php` con un contexto similar a: `Formulario enviado con exito`, esto hace que te lo redirecciona a la página `enviado.php` con un `HEADER` HTTP 3xx y luego contesta el servido con un **GET** HTTP 200 y te sirve la página `enviado.php`, y así evitas que no se vuelva enviar el formulario mediante `POST` otra vez.

Te dejo una imagen más descriptiva:

[image: PRG - Pattern]

Fuente de imágen: [Wikipedia - Post/Redirect/Get](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Tu código seria entonces de la siguiente manera y recuerda que tienes que poner este bloque de código antes de tu código `HTML`, para evitar errores [Header already sent...](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32705/error-en-la-cabecera/32706#32706):

```
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['newsemail'])){
    include("db_files/db.php");
    $newsemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['newsemail']);
    $strSQL = "INSERT INTO newsletter (`email`) VALUES ( '$newsemail')";
    $query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
    unset($_POST['newsemail']);

    // Redirecciona a la página que deseas
    header('Location: 'enviado.php');
}
?>

// Y aqui el resto de tu código HTML
```

Comment: @Trauma - Porque el voto negativo?

Comment: Yo no te he dado el voto negativo pero pienso que puede ser porque es lo mismo que mi respuesta

Comment: Es casi correcta, pero, ¿ y si el usuario vuelve a entrar en la misma página ? El problema tiene otra parte, en la página que genera el formulario. Si es un carrito de la compra, me mostraría el diálogo 2 veces. Me lo enviarian 2 veces. Y me lo cobrarian 2 veces también  :-(

Comment: @AlbertoMier -  Ok... no pasa nada... quería solo saber el porque...

Comment: Te retiro el negativo. Realmente, la pregunta es *como evitar el dialogo*, y vuestras respuestas son correctas. Era yo el equivocado; lo de mostrar o no el formulario y demás *pajas mentales* mías no tienen relación con la pregunta. Rectificar es de sabios, dicen  :-(

Comment: @Trauma - No te preocupes para esto estamos aquí...

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar la funcion de `php` `unset`.

`unset()` destruye las variables especificadas.

El comportamiento de `unset()` dentro de una función puede variar dependiendo de qué tipo de variable que se está tratando de destruir.

Si una variable global es `unset()` dentro de una función, solo la variable local es destruida. La variable en el entorno de la llamada mantendrá el mismo valor anterior a la llamada a `unset()`.

Te dejo un enlace al manual: http://php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php

Ejemplo:

```
$foo = 'bar';
unset($foo);
```

**EDIT**

Prueba a añadir esto:

```
<script>
    var cuenta=0;
    function enviado() {
        if (cuenta == 0) {
            cuenta++;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Despues en la etiqueta `form` tienes que añadir lo siguiente: `onSubmit="return enviado()"`

**EDIT 2**

La solución en este caso es sencilla pero requiere de un pequeño cambio en la función que guarda los datos del formulario. Para evitar ese mensaje, lo que debes hacer es redirigir al usuario después de guardar los cambios.

Imagina que la situación actual es:

```
El usuario entra en /contacto.php, rellena el formulario y le da a Enviar.
El script contacto.php procesa los datos del formulario. Si hay errores, vuelve a mostrar la página con un mensaje. Si todo está bien, guarda los datos y muestra un mensaje de tipo "Hemos recibido tu mensaje. Gracias por contactarnos. Te responderemos pronto".
```

Lo que hay que cambiar es que contacto.php, después de guardar los datos del formulario, debe redirigir a otra página (por ejemplo a la portada) en vez de mostrar el resultado en la misma página. Así ya no se mostrará más ese mensaje de confirmar el reenvío del formulario. Si estás programando PHP "a pelo", la redirección es tan fácil como hacer `header('Location: '.$url);`

Lo he sacado de aqui: http://librosweb.es/foro/pregunta/983/como-hago-para-evitar-el-mensaje-confirmar-reenvio-del-formulario/

Comment: Me sigue saliendo esto al recargar la página: http://i.imgur.com/VjzYnyr.png

Comment: Prueba a poner el html debajo del codigo php

Comment: He editado la pregunta, he puesto el codigo completo del footer

Comment: He editado mi respuesta @PavloB.

Comment: `<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="return enviado()">` he añadido eso y el `<script>...</script>` que me has comentado, pero aún así me sigue apareciendo el alert arriba para "confirmar el envio de formulario" al recargar la página despues de introducir un correo en el campo

Comment: He editado otra vez @PavloB.

Comment: Como puedo obtener la url actual en una variable? Yo utilizaba esto: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI];` pero en ocasiones me daba problemas

Comment: Puedes hacer el redireccionamiento con jjavascrip sino, utlizando reload @PavloB.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48336/discussion-between-alberto-mier-and-pavlo-b).

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48338/discussion-between-pavlo-b-and-alberto-mier).

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo he controlado haciendo algo como lo siguiente aunque solo sirve para omitir reprocesar lo último enviado al refrescar pagina con tecla F5, pero me acomoda bien cuando lo que envío, desaparece de la lista de pendiente por procesar:

```
<?php
session_start();

if( !empty($_GET['txt'])  &&  !( isset($_SESSION['GET_PREVIO']) && !empty($_GET['txt']) && $_SESSION['GET_PREVIO'] == $_GET['txt'] )   )
{
    $_SESSION['GET_PREVIO'] = $_GET['txt'];
    echo "se recibio {$_GET['txt']}";
    //echo "  <script> window.location.href='ddd.php'; </script>";
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='refresh' CONTENT='10'>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method='GET' action='ddd.php'>
            <input type='text' name='txt' >
            <input type='submit' name='btn' value='enviar' >
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo más breve y claro, una solución más común es que tengas dos archivos, uno con el html del formulario y otro con el php que procesa los datos y redirecciona al finalizar el proceso, mas o menos como lo dice @aldanux y @alberto-mier en el EDIT 2. Por ejeplo:

**formulario.php**: Contiene el html y en la etiqueta `<form>` agregar el atributo `action="enviar.php"`

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="POST">
    <p class="footer-contact-info"><?php echo $lang['footer_string_5']; ?></p>
    <input type="email" class="my-form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['footer_string_6']; ?>" name="newsemail" />
    <button class="newsletter-button"><?php echo $lang['footer_string_7'];?></button>
    <br>
</form>
```

**enviar.php**: Contiene el php que inserta los datos en la base de datos:

```
<?php
$resultado = "";
if (isset ($_POST['newsemail'])){
    include("db_files/db.php");
    $newsemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['newsemail']);
    $strSQL = "INSERT INTO newsletter (`email`) VALUES ( '$newsemail')";
    $query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
    if($query){
      $resultado = "exitoso";
    }else{
      $resultado = "error";
    }
}
header('Location: formulario.php?resultado='.$resultado);
?>
```

No es necesario usar el unset para borrar el `$_POST`, después de grabar los datos te redirecciona al formulario nuevamente con valor por url llamado resultado el cual obtienes con un `$_GET` para que controles el mensaje del resultado si lo deseas.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza [unset](http://php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php), si la igualas a otro valor no la destruirás, simplemente tendrá otro valor sea undefined o null, pero estará definida.

Answer (score 0):

mucho más simple todavía... lo solucioné de esta manera:
1. en el method del formulario utilizo GET y
2. por ajax envío normalmente los datos del formulario mediante POST
y me olvidé del tema... gracias por su ayuda ... me sirvió todo

Answer (score 0):

a mi me funciono insertando este script en donde actualizaba.

```js
<script>
// EVITAR REENVIO DE DATOS.
    if (window.history.replaceState) { // verificamos disponibilidad
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href);
}
</script>
```