# ¿Cómo poder eliminar los datos de la página tras recargar la página en PHP?

Tags: php

lo que quiero es:
Tengo una página de prueba, este es el código:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" id="btnEnviar"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="registrar" value="Registrar" id="btnRegistrar">
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
        echo "Pulsado boton enviar";
    } elseif (isset($_POST['registrar'])) {
        echo "Se ha pulsado el botón btnRegistrar.";
    } else {
        echo "";
    }
?>
```

La salida es: Pulsado el boton enviar
Estoy aprendiendo php y lo que quiero que cuando recargo la página no me muestre el mensaje, me indique el campo en blanco, como si fuera la primera vez que se carga la página. Pero no soy capaz de conseguirlo, que cada vez que recargue la página en vez de salir el mensaje del último botón que se ha pulsado no aparezca ningún mensaje.

Comment: No entiendo exactamente tu problema o el mensaje que debería aparecer o no, pero creo que esta respuesta que di te pueda ayudar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/33153/6491

Comment: No se si es posible hacer lo que tu quieres, pues al recargar la pagina es como (valga la redundancia) si se recargara todo el contenido nuevamente, algo que se me ocurre es que crees un localStorage y validar, o si no que el mensaje sea dinamico con una base de datos, es decir, creas una tabla y cuando recargas la pagina haces una petición validando si ya aparecio ese mensaje por primera vez sino aparece ningun registro lo muestras de lo contrario no, todo depende a tu requerimiento.

Comment: No queda muy claro el problema. Creo que quieres ir descartando botones ¿? ¿Que la 1ª vez de muestre el mensaje del botón `enviar`, la 2ª vez el del botón `registrar`....?  ¿Y luego? Eso se puede hacer a través de manipulaciones complicadas, pero no le veo demasiado sentido, mucho menos sabiendo que existe algo que se llama ¡Ajax!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso del atributo `autocomplete="off"` en tu form.
Prueba así:

```
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" id="btnEnviar"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="registrar" value="Registrar" id="btnRegistrar">
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
        echo "Pulsado boton enviar";
    } elseif (isset($_POST['registrar'])) {
        echo "Se ha pulsado el botón btnRegistrar.";
    } else {
        echo "";
    }
?>
```

El atributo también puede ser usado en un solo input :

```
<input name="" id="" class"" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que entiendo es que, al presionar f5 no se "reenvíe" la data anteriormente mandada ¿cierto?
puedes añadir esta porción de código:

```
<script>
    if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
        window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
    }
</script>
```

Esto lo que hace es que al recargar la pagina no se envía ninguna data anteriormente enviada.
Espero haber entendido bien tu pregunta.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/393233)