# Cambiar el color y Limpiar los errores - CSS

Tags: php, css

Estoy creando un login siguiendo un ejemplo
Y para mi conveniencia, este ya viene con las alertas de errores.
Pues bien, el tema está, que al recargar la página, estos errores no se reinician, no desaparecen de la visual al momento de dar F5. Ya que al apretar F5, pide un reenvío de formulario, y pues trata de mandar nuevamente datos.
La idea es que si recargo la página, estos desaparezcan.

Por otro lado, el color de los errores es default, cosa que necesito cambiar.
Logre cambiarlos a lo que quiero, pero editando el style del span en html.
Lo que quiero hacer, es mover eso, a CSS, pero mis intentos no han dado frutos.
Supongo que es por que está dentro del span, pero tampoco me ha resultado el llamado de span.help-block que traté:
Asi es como lo tengo en el html:

```
<div class="divinput form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <label>Usuario</label> 
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control inputl" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
    <span class="help-block" --> style="color: darkorange" <--- ><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### UPDATE #1

He podido realizar el cambio de color deseado
Revisé las clases que interferían, y además de `help-block` hay que agregar `has-error`. De este modo, el CSS quedó así:

```
.has-error .help-block {
    color: darkorange;
}
```

Comment: Sobre el reenvío al recargar la página: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45656609

Comment: Perfecto! Te agradecería agregarlo como respuesta traducida, para marcarla como correcta :3

Comment: Gracias, ahora mismo no tengo el tiempo para una respuesta más completa. Por acá hay unas soluciones muy buenas en SOes https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33142/como-evitar-reenv%c3%ado-del-formulario