# ¿Como enviar correctamente datos de un Formulario POST a la misma pagina?

Tags: php, html

Tengo una pagina web, donde quiero recibir algunos datos en la misma pagina enviados por un formulario POST, este es mi avance de mi código:

```
<?php  if(isset($con_in_recepcion_es)){?>
<div class="container contenerdor_dideo">
<iframe src="<?php echo $con_in_recepcion_es; ?>" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <form method="POST" action="auditorio.php">
    <input type="text" name="con_in_recepcion_ori" value="<?php echo $con_in_recepcion_ori ?>">
    <button type="button"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Au</b> </div>
  </form>
<?php }elseif (isset($con_in_recepcion_ori)) {
echo "DATO";
} ?>
```

Al momento de dar clic en el botón, me manda a la misma pagina, todo es correcto hasta aquí, pero mi duda es que al dar clic al botón regresar, me sale un mensaje diciendo "Confirmar reenvío del formulario", entonces quiero evitar eso, no se si hay alguna manera de regresar sin que salga dicho mensaje. Les agradezco su tiempo y cualquier idea es bien recibida.

Comment: Puedes ver una pregunta similar en 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33142/como-evitar-reenv%C3%ADo-del-formulario

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre me imagino que tienes dos botones.
Los Podrias definir de esta manera

```
 <input type="submit" name="next" value="next">
 <input type="submit" name="return" value="return">
```

y como lo estas definidiendo en la misma pagina tendrias que validarlo

```
 if(!empty($_POST)){
     if($_POST['next'])
     {
         echo 'pasa algo'; 
     } elseif($_POST['return'] == 'return'){
         echo 'pasa otra cosa';
     }
 }
```