# Error Message: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter-3, session

lo que pasa es que al momento se subir mi pagina a un hosting me esta saliendo el siguiente error, y gracias de ante mano.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/gesportcomco/public_html/v2/application/controllers/Gesport.php:1)

Filename: Session/Session.php

Line Number: 143

Backtrace:

File: /home/gesportcomco/public_html/v2/application/controllers/Gesport.php
Line: 5
Function: __construct

File: /home/gesportcomco/public_html/v2/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Intenta borrar caché. El mensaje es claro: _el valor que sea que estés enviando ya existe en caché_.

Comment: [Las funciones PHP que envían o modifican las cabeceras HTTP se deben ejecutar antes de que se haya empezado a enviar la página solicitada al usuario.](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/32706/6491) deberías mostrar el código relevante

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave - eso no es cierto... mira el link en mi comentario

Comment: @aldanux, tienes razón. me guié mas por la información del mensaje. Ojalá que el OP vea tu enlace y ésta sea la respuesta que el está buscando.