# Error de Session_Start

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Estaba copiando a una pc que tengo, un viejo sistema importe su base de datos y fui a probarlo (esta se llama **base_projecto**)  ocurrio que la base de datos tenia otro nombre diferente al que yo había puesto, lo cambie en conexion. (me decia que era **base_sancion**)

Cuando entro al sistema este funciona, me conecto usando el usuario y la contraseña, pero al meterme a los menus salieron errores de los QUERY de MYSQL porque la base de datos no era la misma, en realidad era **base_sancion**. siguiente a esto sin desconectar el usuario, cambie el nombre de la base de datos de **base_proyecto** a **base_sancion** y guarde, luego actualice el navegador

Mi sistema trabaja con usuario y contraseña, apartir de ese momento empezo a salir este error:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache  limiter - headers already sent (output started at  C:\wamp\www\prueba_victor\Sistema de Sanciones\conexion.php:1) in C:\wamp\www\prueba_victor\Sistema de Sanciones\home.php on line 4

Creo que fue que yo me conecte al sistema con la base de datos usando el primer nombre, luego sin desconectarme cambie la base de datos y el nombre de conexion y empezó el error. `se creo uno doble sesion?`

Mi sistema funcionaba bien porque en la pc de donde lo saque, yo lo probe antes.

Este es uno de sus formularios, ya que todos dan el mismo error pero en la linea donde esta el inicio de session.

Trate cambiando la posicion de la sesion, antes de html, luego de html, dejandola sola, en fin.

home

```
 <?php
    include "conexion.php";
    global $cone;
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) || $_SESSION["user_id"]==null){
        print "<script>alert(\"Acceso invalido!\");window.location='login.php';</script>";
    }
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>.: HOME :.</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        </head>
        <body>
        <?php include "php/navbar.php"; ?>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Bienvenido</h2>
    <?php
    $user_id=$_SESSION["user_id"];
    echo "Usuario: ".$user_id."<br/>";
    $registros=mysqli_query($cone,"select * from user where id=$user_id");
    $reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros);
    $nombre1 = $reg["nombre1"];
    $nombre2 = $reg["nombre2"];
    $apellido1 = $reg["apellido1"];
    $apellido2 = $reg["apellido2"];
    global $var;
    $var=($nombre1." ".$nombre2." ".$apellido1." ".$apellido2);
    echo $var;
    ?>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
        </body>
    </html>


Conexion:

    <?php
    $host="localhost";
    $usua="root";
    $pass="";
    $base="php_practica";

    $cone = new mysqli($host,$usua,$pass,$base);

    if ($cone->connect_errno) {
       echo "Falló la conexión a MySQL: (" . $cone->connect_errno . ") " . $cone->connect_error;    
    } 
    ?>
```

listado:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "conexion.php";
global $cone;
if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) || $_SESSION["user_id"]==null)
print "<script>alert(\"Acceso invalido!\");window.location='login.php';</script>";
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>Listado del personal sancionado</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include "php/navbar.php"; ?>
<h1>Listado de Personal</h1>
<div><table align=center>
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th><center>Número</th>
            <th><center>Primer Nombre</th>
            <th><center>Segundo Nombre</th>
            <th><center>Primer Apellido</th>
            <th><center>Segundo Apellido</th>
            <th><center>Cédula</th>
            <th><center>Rango</th>
            <th><center>Opciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<?php
$contador=0;
$registros=mysqli_query($cone,"select * from personal");
while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
{
$contador=1+$contador;
echo "<td>".$contador."</td>";
echo "<td>".$reg['nombre1']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$reg['nombre2']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$reg['apellido1']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$reg['apellido2']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$reg['cedula']."</td>";
$sql =mysqli_query($cone,"SELECT a.cedula, a.rango_id, b.rango
FROM   personal a LEFT JOIN rangos  b ON a.rango_id = b.id_rango
ORDER BY a.cedula ASC");
$sql2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
echo "<td>".$sql2['rango']."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<a onClick='return confirmSav();' href=actualizar.php?cedula=".$reg['cedula']." >editar<a/>"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<a onClick='return confirmDel();' href=procesar3.php?cedula=".$reg['cedula']." >eliminar<a/>"."</td>";
echo "</tbody>";
}
?>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
function confirmSav()
{
  var agree=confirm("¿Desea modificar este registro? ");
  if (agree)
  return true ;
else
   return false ;
}
</script>

<script>
function confirmDel()
{
  var agree=confirm("¿Desea eliminar este registro? ");
  if (agree)
  return true ;
else
   return false ;
}
</script>
```

Comment: prueba poner el `<html>` tag justo después del cierre `?>`, ej: `... ?><html>` y me cuentas

Comment: no mejoro, sigue dando el error

Comment: Quita el `session_start();`

Comment: vale era para comprobar si tenia un espacio... pero ahora leyendo mejor el mensaje del fallo dice que hay ya un `output` en `conexion.php`... pon `session_start()` justo después de `<?php`.... (supongo que tendrás algún echo/fallo en `conexion.php`) muestra ese fichero...

Comment: si lo quito, me sale el error luego da el aviso de acceso invalido y luego se regresa a login

Comment: agregare la conexion

Comment: El programa "conexion.php" esta generando algun tipo de error o echo, la funcion session_start solo se puede inicializar si no se envio ningun header, tu problema radica en ese programa.

Comment: ¿Que error te sale?

Comment: el que esta en la pregunta

Comment: Tienes un fallo en la conexión (Sea contraseña, user, db o host) verifica si esos son los correctos

Comment: el usuario y la clave son esos, igual el host pues ejecuto asi el sistema LOCALHOST/xyz

Comment: y la base de datos?

Comment: igual php_practica

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53822/discussion-between-hector-seguro-and-victor-a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El fallo está en que tienes un fallo en tu `conexion.php` y eso hace que salte el `echo ...mensaje de error...` antes del `session_start()`

Primero tendrías que arreglar el fallo de conexión después tienes que ver como manejar los fallos de estos tipos.

Es decir que quieres hacer al tener un fallo en la conexión a la base de datos, mostrar error al usuario? No creo que sea una buena idea... pero esto es otro tema.

> Las funciones PHP que envían o modifican las cabeceras HTTP se deben
>   ejecutar antes de que se haya empezado a enviar la página solicitada
>   al usuario.

En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/32706/6491) he dejado todos los motivos que puedan causar: `headers already sent`

Poniendo el `session_start();` antes del `include "conexion.php";` te soluciona el problema con `header already sent` por el momento:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "conexion.php";
global $cone;
```

Comment: al ejecutar la conexion sola no muestra error, aparte de que los selects y radio button se cargan bien

Comment: estuve revisando y creo que se cual error era, mi sistema tiene dos archivos de conexion, el primero esta dentro de la carpeta raiz, y el segundo esta en otra carpeta llamada PHP, este segundo archivo tenia un espacio luego de cerrar el PHP algo asi ?>_

Comment: pero de igual manera aparece el error por un momento y luego se borra

Comment: `session_start()` DEBE ser la primera instrucción SIEMPRE. Si hay otros archivos haciendo `echo` o algo más antes de hacer session_start, va a fallar porque los headers se envían antes de tiempo.

Comment: acomode como me dijiste, pero ahora da error en un solo achivo

Comment: @VictorA. - Recuerda que el error `headers already sent` es un `warning` y no un `fatal error` por eso te muestra el contenido igual... pues lo que comentas de que tienes doble conexión quizás debes usar `include_once` o `require_once` para no repetir... y me alegro que hayas encontrado el error del espacio..

Comment: borrare esa doble conexion, pero como te digo, ahora ya no da el error en el home, que es el que muestro en la pregunta, sino en otros dos formulario

Comment: @VictorA. - Pero cual error? `header already sent`?

Comment: si ese mismo error

Comment: @VictorA. - Pues lo mismo...  comprueba que no tengas ningún output/espacio antes de modificar la cabecera/headers ...

Comment: publicare mi codigo

Comment: a ambos lo acomode como me especificaste}

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53826/discussion-between-aldanux-and-victor-a).