# Header que no quiere funcionar

Tags: php

quiero redireccionar a una página web con header en php pero me arroja un error que dice algo como:

```
PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/sitio/public_html/includeses/analyticstracking.php:1)
```

y despues menciona el número de línea donde tengo el header definido

```
$variableApasar = 200;
header('Location: pagina.php?var=' . base64_encode($variableApasar));
```

PHP qué te ocurre ?

Comment: Saludos, Yo con anterioridad tuve este tipo de problemas y es como lo dice el compañero Tygreton. Tambien puedes utilizar estas funciones definidas por el PHP, como Son `ob_start();`
al principio de tu Sitio web y al final `ob_end_flush();`

Comment: es una página que resuelve un post en la misma pagina y cuando finaliza el proceso de grabación de datos en la página, quiero redireccionarla a una página anterior... No entiendo dónde tengo que poner ese ob_start() si en la pagina que estoy procesando...

Comment: si usas un truco como `echo "<script  language='javascript'>window.location='pagina.php?var='".$variable."' </script>";` te servirá?

Comment: en lugar del header ?

Comment: pero como paso la variable base64_encode($variableApasar) ?

Comment: Intenta usarlo en la pagina donde estas haciendo la redireccion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las funciones PHP que envían o modifican las cabeceras HTTP se deben ejecutar antes de que se haya empezado a enviar la página solicitada al usuario. Si no, se producirá el siguiente error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
(output started at file:line)
```

Las funciones PHP que modifican las cabeceras HTTP son las siguientes:

```
header() / header_remove()
session_start() / session_regenerate_id()
setcookie() / setrawcookie()
```

Y las formas de empezar a enviar contenidos al usuario antes de que se ejecuten esas funciones pueden ser a su vez intencionadas o no intencionadas:

**Intencionadas:**

- Mostrar información con print o echo
- Volcar el contenido de variables con `var_dump()`
- Utilizar alguna de estas funciones: `printf(), trigger_error(), vprintf(), ob_flush(), readfile() o passthru()`.
- Añadir código HTML antes de la etiqueta `<?php` de apertura

**No intencionadas:**

- Añadir algún espacio en blanco antes de `<?php` o después de `?>`
- El BOM (Byte Order Mark) de UTF-8
- Mensajes de error o notices producidos con anterioridad

Comment: es una página que resuelve un post en la misma pagina y cuando finaliza el proceso de grabación de datos en la página, quiero redireccionarla a una página anterior...

Comment: Hola, te comento que el sitio reporto que estas realizando **Respuestas duplicadas**, incluso esta pregunta ya tiene [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32705/error-en-la-cabecera-warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-alrea),  Revisar [answer].