# ¿Como solucionar Deprecated mysql_connect en un archivo install?

Tags: php, mysql

Me podria ayudar alguien con este error (Deprecated mysql_connect), les explico: Tengo un viejo script, este contiene una tipica interfaz de instalación. Todo va bien hasta el paso de finalizar instalación donde me sale estos dos errores:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
>   will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
>   /home/site/public_html/test/install/database.php on line 14
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/site/public_html/test/install/database.php:14) in
>   /home/site/public_html/test/install/install.php on line 105

El archivo batabase.php contiene:

```
<?php
include 'include/db.php';

class MYSQL_DB {
    var $connection;
    function MYSQL_DB(){
        $this->connection = mysql_connect(HOST, USER, PASS) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db(NAME, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    function mysql_exec_batch ($p_query, $p_transaction_safe = true){
        if($p_transaction_safe){
            $p_query = 'START TRANSACTION;'.$p_query.'; COMMIT;';
        };
        $query_split = preg_split ("/[;]+/", $p_query);
        foreach($query_split as $command_line){
            $command_line = trim($command_line);
            if($command_line != ''){
                $query_result = mysql_query($command_line);
                if($query_result == 0){
                    break;
                };
            };
        };
        return $query_result;
    }
    function query($query){
        return mysql_query($query, $this->connection);
    }
};
$database = new MYSQL_DB;
?>
```

El archivo install.php contiene de la linea 99 hasta 109 (del error):

```
function ImportDB(){
        global $database;
        $str = file_get_contents('include/database.sql');
        $str = preg_replace("'%PREFIX%'", 'alpha', $str);
        $result = $database->mysql_exec_batch($str);
        if($result){
            header('Location: index.php?step=5');
        }else{
            header('Location: index.php?step=3&error=1');
        }
    }
```

Comment: mira esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/32706/6491) donde te explica el error `headers already sent` el otro es solo un warning... pero procedería de actualizar el código por tema de seguridad... tienes que mirar donde llamas la función `ImportDB`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes múltiples opciones:

Puedes desactivar los mensajes de error

```
// Al principio de cada archivo pon lo siguiente
error_reporting(0);
```

Puedes hacerlo a través de la línea de comandos, cuestión de adaptar la función `ImportDB`:

```
<?php
$comando = 'mysql -u usuario -p contraseña base_a_cargar < archivo.sql';

$ultima_linea = system($comando, $retornoCompleto);

print_r( $ultima_linea );
print_r( $retornoCompleto );
```

Puedes migrar el código a PDO o MYSQL, ejemplo MySQLi, simplemente adaptalo a tus necesidades:

```
// Establecemos la conexión
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'mi_usuario', 'mi_contraseña', 'mi_bd');

// verificamos que sea correcta 
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error de Conexión (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
        . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

// Se asume conexión en $mysqli

// Recuperamos el fichero como un string
$fileSQL = file_get_contents('ruta_fichero.sql');


/* Ejecutar consulta multiquery */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($fileSQL)) {
    do {
        /* Almacenar y mostrat juego de resultados */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                print_r($row);
                echo "<br/>";
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* mostrar divisor */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
      // Avanzar al siguiente resultado
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* Cerrar conexión */
$mysqli->close();
```

> Desde la versión 5.5.0 de PHP las funciones de [mysql original](http://php.net/manual/es/changelog.mysql.php) son declaradas obsoletas y emiten un error **E_DEPRECATED**, en **PHP >= 7.0.0 han sido eliminadas**.

---

1. La primera opción es poco recomendable, aún que si solo lo vas a utilizar el Script una vez y de forma controlada poder ser factible.
2. La segunda opción puede ser peligrosa y debe ser utilizada con sumo cuidado ya que es utilizada a la línea de comandos, debemos garantizar que sólo se va a ejecutar aquello que nosotros queramos y que no habrá opción de que un usuario malicioso pueda ejecutar cualquier cosa, que no se pueda ejecutar código arbitrario.
3. La tercera opción es la más recomendable, migrar a MySQLi o PDO es lo que deberías hacer, en este caso concreto apostaría por MySQLi ya que PDO no soporta 100% sentencias múltiples y podría darte problemas.

---

Un ejemplo con tú clase de conexión intentando modificar lo menos posible.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class MYSQL_DB {
    protected $connection;
    public $log = array();

    // adaptamos el constructor
    function __construct()
    {
        // Cambiamos la conexión a mysqli
        $this->connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'mi_usuario', 'mi_contraseña', 'mi_bd');

        if ($this->connection->connect_error) {
            // Si falla la conexión finalizamos el script
            die('Error de Conexión (' . $this->connection->connect_errno . ') '. $this->connection->connect_error);
        }
        $this->log[] = 'Conexión ok';
    }

    // Adaptamos el método mysql_exec_batch
    function mysql_exec_batch ($p_query, $p_transaction_safe = true)
    {
        $this->log[] =  $p_query;
        // Declaramos variable para los resultados 
        $query_result = Array();

        if($p_transaction_safe){
                // comprobamos si se pide transacciones
            if($this->connection->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE)) {
                $this->log[] = 'Transacción iniciada';
            } else {
                $this->log[] = 'Error en transacción (' . $this->connection->errno . ') '. $this->connection->error;                
            }
        }

        /* Comprobamos consulta multiquery  correctamente */
        if ($this->connection->multi_query($p_query)) {
            $this->log[] =  'Mutiquery ok';            
            // recorremos los resultados de la consulta
            $i = 0; // contador

            do {
                /* Almacenar y mostrat juego de resultados */
                if ($result = $this->connection->store_result()) {
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                         // Almacenamos los resultados
                        $query_result[$i][] =  $row;
                    }
                    // Liberamos el resultado
                    $result->free();
                }

                if ($this->connection->more_results()) {
                    ++$i; // Incrementamos contador
                } else {
                    $this->log[] = 'Se recorrieron todos los resultados';            
                    break;
                }

            // Avanzar al siguiente conjunto de resultados
            } while ($this->connection->next_result());
        } else {
            $this->log[] = 'Error en multiquery (' . $this->connection->errno . ') '. $this->connection->error;
        }

        if($p_transaction_safe){
            // Hacemos commit
            if($this->connection->commit()) {
                $this->log[] = 'Commit ok';
            } else {
                $this->log[] = 'Error en commit (' . $this->connection->errno . ') '. $this->connection->error;
            }
        }

        // Retornamos el Array de resultados
        $this->log[] = 'Return result';
        $this->log['resultados'] = $query_result;
        return $query_result;
    }

}

$database = new MYSQL_DB;


$sql = '
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tabla;

CREATE TABLE tabla(TABLA_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO tabla VALUES(123456789);
INSERT INTO tabla VALUES(284561);

SELECT * FROM tabla;
SELECT * FROM tabla;
';


// $str = file_get_contents('include/database.sql');
$str = preg_replace("'%PREFIX%'", 'alpha', $sql);
$result = $database->mysql_exec_batch($str);

if($result){
    print_r($result);
}else{
    print_r($result);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($database->log);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Hola Xerif, entiendo gran parte de lo explicado, pero aun no consigo ajustarlo al codigo que me dejaste. ¿Me podrias dejar un ejemplo en mi codigo? ... Gracias.

Comment: @Carla te he añadido un ejemplo in la respuesta. Lo hice desde el móvil, por lo que es posible que tenga algún error de sintaxis, remplaza el archivo batabase.php con este código, haz antes un respaldo del archivo por si acaso.

Comment: Xerif no puedes indicarle que haga un `die` si la conexión falla, porque el archivo `insertar.php` está usando `header location`. Entonces si hay errores en la conexión, seguirá teniendo el mismo `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...`. El código debe ser controlado silenciosamente (por ejemplo recogiendo los posibles mensajes de error en alguna variable) y decir todo en los `header location` o cambiar totalmente de estrategia. Antes de los `header location` no debe salir absolutamente nada en pantalla.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si la conexion falla y salta el die, nunca llegara a los header y entiendo que tampoco tendria sentido continuar con el script se muestran los errores y muere. Si te fijas en el original tambien tenemos un die si la conexion falla.

Comment: No le veo sentido a usar `die` con `header location`. Nunca los uso, ni uno ni otro... pero eso es cuestión de gustos, o más bien de costumbres. No me parece algo lógico que el programa tenga tres posibles salidas: 1. por la vía de `die` solamente cuando la conexión falle, y otras dos  por `header location` cuando haya éxito o haya cualquier otro error. Lo correcto sería tener siempre dos únicas vías de salida. En este caso, si ha optado por los `header location` haciendo que el error sea mencionado ahí, en la redirección que indica error. Salir por `die` puede dar resultados no controlados.

Comment: De hecho, si te fijas, su código tiene un `die` y la conexión es posible que no se esté haciendo, y al mismo tiempo está teniendo el warning que menciono. Es entonces posible que haga el `die` y devuelva el control a `install.php`, encontrándose en seguida con el `header location` después de haber ejecutado una salida por pantalla con el `die`. No me parece que el código respete esa regla impuesta por `header location`. Es lo que ocurre cuando llamas código así desde otros archivos. No sé si ves a lo que me refiero.

Comment: Gracia por toda tu ayuda Xerif, pero creo que el script tiene muchas mas errores que al principio pensaba. El codigo que me diste me da dos errores y extiende errores al install.php tambien. Asi que no creo que vale haciendo esfuerzos con el sctipt. De todas maneras agradezco mucho tu esfuerzo. Un saludo

Comment: @A.Cedano entiendo lo que quieres decir, pero un `die` es lo mismo que un `exit` y finalizan la ejecución, da igual lo que haya despues eso no es el problema. Los erres `Warning: Cannot modify header` obviamente son por que se estan lanzazndo los `Warning: E_DEPRECATED` antes de los header, pero este tipo de errores no afectan directamente a la ejecucion son advetencias, la ejecucion continua normal.

Comment: @Carla Acabo de editar el ejemplo para hacerlo mas completo y lo he probado y funciona. es dificil dal una solucionn completa sin conocer el codigo complero y revisar a que mas afecta, por eso una de las soluciones que aporte fue la de esconder los errores que en cierto modo puede parchear el problema aun que no es la solucion recomendada.

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje te lo dice claramente. La función `mysql_connect()` usada en la línea 14 de tu `database.php` está desaprobada por motivos de seguridad. Deberías actualizar gran parte de tu código, ya que actualmente está muy vulnerable a ataques. Por ejemplo debes reemplazar todas las funciones que usas para la conexión, y en lugar de usar `mysql` debes usar `mysqli`.

Para el caso de `mysql_connect()` debes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
$this->connection = mysqli_connect( 'host', 'username', 'password');
```

Además debes reemplazar también `mysql_select_db()` de la siguiente forma:

```
$database = mysqli_select_db($link, 'database');
```

Y así con todas las demás funciones desaprobadas. Te sugiero que busques información al respecto. Puedes leer como hacerlo [aquí](https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/9199/post/3-Smoothly-Migrate-your-PHP-Code-using-the-Old-MySQL-extension-to-MySQLi.html#tutorial-video) o [aquí](https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/PHP/1405293-Pasar-de-MySql-a-Mysqli.html).

Puedes ver el uso de `mysqli_connect()` [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp)

Puedes ver el uso de `mysqli_select_db()` [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_select_db.asp)

Comment: Hola Adriana, te lo agradezco mucho pero no he solucionado nada, me sigue saliendo el mismo error. Hice los cambios que me dijiste pero da el mismo en la linea 14.

Comment: Adriana, ¿por qué no haces referencia a la documentación oficial de PHP, la cual además está en castellano y es mucho mejor que w3schools? Y, ya que estamos innovando, el estilo orientado a objetos es recomendable, con respecto al estilo procedural.