# Problema con header() en PHP

Tags: php, cabeceras-http

Tengo esta advertencia:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

No sé qué pueda tener mal en header.

Este es mi código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
 *
 * @author Zarate
-->
<?php
include ('serv.php');

$fechaInicio=$_POST['fInicio'];
$fechaFin=$_POST['fFin'];

if (isset($_POST['excel'])) {
    
    //archivo
    header('Content-Type:text/csv; charset=latin1');
//    header('Content-Type:text/csv; charset=latin1');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Solicitud_De_Cuentas.csv"');
    
    //archivo saliente
    $salida=fopen('php://output', 'w');
    
    fputcsv($salida, array('Nombre', 'Apellidos', 'Nombre Completo', 'Alias E-mail', 'Titulo', 'Puesto', 'Delegacion', 'Departamento', 'Direccion', 'Ciudad', 'Estado', 'Telefono', 'Extencion', 'Matricula', 'CURP', 'Num. Seg Social', 'Servidor de correo actual', 'Forma de Acceso', 'Sist. Operativo de la PC', 'Nombre de la PC', 'pwd'));
    
    $csv=$conect->query("SELECT * FROM registros where Fecha BETWEEN '$fechaInicio' and '$fechaFin'");
    while ($filaR=$csv->fetch_assoc())
            fputcsv($salida, array($filaR['Nombre'],
                                    $filaR['Apellidos'],
                                    $filaR['Nombre Completo'],
                                    $filaR['Alias E-mail'],
                                    $filaR['Titulo'],
                                    $filaR['Puesto'],
                                    $filaR['Delegacion'],
                                    $filaR['Departamento'],
                                    $filaR['Direccion'],
                                    $filaR['Ciudad'],
                                    $filaR['Estado'],
                                    $filaR['Telefono'],
                                    $filaR['Extension'],
                                    $filaR['Matricula'],
                                    $filaR['CURP'],
                                    $filaR['Num. Seg Social'],
                                    $filaR['Servidor de correo actual'],
                                    $filaR['Forma de Acceso'],
                                    $filaR['Sist. Operativo de la PC'],
                                    $filaR['Nombre de la PC'],
                                    $filaR['pwd']));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Las funciones PHP que envían o modifican las cabeceras HTTP se deben ejecutar antes de que se haya empezado a enviar la página solicitada al usuario. Si no, se producirá el siguiente error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
(output started at file:line)
```

Las funciones PHP que modifican las cabeceras HTTP son las siguientes:

```
header() / header_remove()
session_start() / session_regenerate_id()
setcookie() / setrawcookie()
```

Y las formas de empezar a enviar contenidos al usuario antes de que se ejecuten esas funciones pueden ser a su vez intencionadas o no intencionadas:

**Intencionadas:**

- Mostrar información con print o echo
- Volcar el contenido de variables con `var_dump()`
- Utilizar alguna de estas funciones: `printf(), trigger_error(), vprintf(), ob_flush(), readfile() o passthru()`.
- Añadir código HTML antes de la etiqueta `<?php` de apertura

**No intencionadas:**

- Añadir algún espacio en blanco antes de `<?php` o después de `?>`
- El BOM (Byte Order Mark) de UTF-8
- Mensajes de error o notices producidos con anterioridad

Comment: Solo añadiría que con `headers_sent()`  se puede detectar donde se inició el envío de cabeceras, a veces es un dolor de cabeza cuadro alguien deja algún espacio suelto en algún sitio que no debe. http://php.net/manual/es/function.headers-sent.php

Comment: Hola, te comento que el sitio reporto que estas realizando **Respuestas duplicadas**, incluso esta pregunta ya tiene [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32705/error-en-la-cabecera-warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-alrea),  Revisar [answer].

Answer (score 2):

El mensaje de

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Es enviado por que estás enviando información extra o cambiando la información que se envía en los headers de la respuesta HTTP cuando ya enviaste información previa de contenido. En el caso muy específico de tu código es por que estás enviando **tags de xml en las primeras 5 líneas de tu código**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
 *
 * @author Zarate
-->
```

Y después estás queriendo cambiar la información de los headers para indicar que vas a enviar un archivo csv descargable con estas otras líneas de código.

```
header('Content-Type:text/csv; charset=latin1');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Solicitud_De_Cuentas.csv"');
```

Elimina las primeras 5 cinco lineas de tu código para que ya no aparezca el mensaje de aviso.