# Error con $_SESSION PHP

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo una página con `MVC` donde el usuario se puede registrar, loguear y editar su usuario,contraseña y email, todo bien hasta aquí, en la barra de navegación de la página hay un botón llamado **Usuarios**, al cual sólo se puede acceder cuando te *logueas*,cuando el usuario hace login sí funciona, pero si no está logueado en la página, al oprimir el botón debería redirigirte a la página para ingresar, pero me lanza un error cuando esto ocurre:

> **Notice: Undefined index: validar.**
>
> **Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by(output started at C:\wamp...**

Este es el código **PHP**:

- **MODELO:**

  ```
  public static function vistaUsuariosModel($datosModel,$tabla){

       $stmt= Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT id,usuario,password,email FROM $tabla");
       $stmt->execute();
       return $stmt->fetchall();    
       $stmt->close();
   }
  ```
- **VISTA:**

  ```php
  <?php
      session_start();
      if(!$_SESSION["validar"]){
          header("location:index.php?action=ingresar");
          exit();
      }
  ?>
  <h1>USUARIOS</h1>

      <table border="1">

          <thead>

              <tr>
                  <th>Usuario</th>
                  <th>Contraseña</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Editar</th>
                  <th>Borrar</th>

              </tr>

          </thead>

          <tbody>
              <?php
              $b=new MvcController();
              $b->vistaUsuariosController();
              ?>
          </tbody>

      </table>

  <?php

  if(isset($_GET["action"])){
      if($_GET["action"]== "cambio"){
          echo "<h1>Actualización Exitosa</h1>";
      }
  }

  ?>
  ```
- **CONTROLADOR:**

  ```
       public static function ingresoUsuarioController(){

              if(isset($_POST["usuarioIngreso"])){

                  $datosController = array("usuario"=>$_POST["usuarioIngreso"],"password"=>$_POST["passwordIngreso"]);
                  $respuesta = Datos::ingresoUsuarioModel($datosController,"usuarios");
                  if($respuesta["usuario"]==$_POST["usuarioIngreso"] && $respuesta["password"]==$_POST["passwordIngreso"]){

                      session_start();
                      $_SESSION["validar"]=true;
                      header("location:index.php?action=usuarios");

                  }else{
                      header("location:index.php?action=fallo");
                  }
              }
          }
  ```

He tratado de encontrar el error, pero no doy con el, si alguien sabe qué puede ser, sería de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Mira a ver si esto te puede ayudar... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129491/problema-con-header-en-php/129535#129535

Comment: Estas tratando de utilizar la variable `$_SESSION["validar"]` que puede estar no definida, lo que provoca que se envie el **Notice: Undefined index: validar.** y envie las cabeceras antes de tiempo, puedes utilizar por ejemplo `isset()` en el condicional. Ej: `if(!isset($_SESSION["validar"])) {/*code*/}`

Comment: Posible duplicado de [PHP y la función header(location: )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19791/php-y-la-funci%c3%b3n-headerlocation)

Comment: @Xerif con esto se resuelve el problema!

Comment: @Jesús Me alegro, veo que el compañero Marcos ya te dejo una respuesta indicando lo mismo. Un saludo.

Comment: @Xerif, tu solución funciona, siempre y cuando no se use `$_SESSION["validar"] = false` para forzar una "Re-autenticación"

Comment: @Marcos Cierto, buen apunte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El `Notice: Undefined index: validar.` ocurre porque en tu vista estas haciendo:

```
if(!$_SESSION["validar"]){
```

Cuando la variable aún no existe. Para evitar esto una opción es:

- Usar [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php), así:

  ```
  if (!isset($_SESSION["validar"]) || !$_SESSION["validar"]) {
  ```
- O, si tienes `PHP v7`, usar el operador [`Fusión de null (??)`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php) (*sugerido por @Aprendiz*), así:

  ```
  $validado = $_SESSION["validar"] ?? false;
  if (!$validado) {
  ```

---

Luego el `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent...` surge por el haberse impreso el `Notice: Undefined index: validar.` y para que la función [`header`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) funcione es necesario que no hayan ocurrido salidas antes de su ejecución.

En otras palabras, el primer mensaje de advertencia provoca el segundo.
Solucionando la primer advertencia, la segunda también ser solucionará.

---

#### Observación:

En tu modelo estas cerrando la conexión a la DB después de hacer `return`. Ese código **nunca** se ejecutará.
Si realmente quíeres cerrar la conexión, deberías hacerlo así:

```
$stmt->execute();
$records = $stmt->fetchall();    
$stmt->close();
return $records;
```

Vale la pena mencionar que no es necesario que cierres la conexión, ya que esta se cierra sola cuando termina la ejecución del proceso completo.

Comment: Creo que también pudiera hacer `$_SESSION['validar'] ?? 'no existe aun';` como sintaxis acortada que válida el uso de `empty` e `isset`

Comment: Gracias con esto ya funciona

Comment: @Marcos solo asignando está evaluación a una variable la cual luego se puede imprimir

Comment: Te entiendo ahora, cuando tenga acceso a una PC reviso y comento amigo @Marcos ya que ando fuera

Comment: @Aprendiz, he agregado una solución adicional usando el operador `??`

Answer (score 5):

Pon esto al principio `ob_start();`
y esto al final `ob_end_flush();`
Y aquí la explicación:

> `ob_start()` inicia un buffer que lo que hace es capturar todas las
>   salidas, y hasta que no se realiza el `ob_end_flush()` no se envían
>   por lo tanto no te muestra el error que no puedes enviar varias veces
>   las cabeceras porque simplemente las guarda y luego las envía cuando
>   se realiza el `ob_end_flush()`

Comment: Sería genial la explicación aquí por dos razones para no mandar al OP a un recurso externo y para mejorar la calidad de tu aporte

Comment: ah perfecto! es que estoy con el móvil! En cuanto llegue a casa, realizo la explicación extendida... @Aprendiz gracias

Comment: Interesante esta respuesta, ya que en Chrome con la solucion de @Marcos funciona perfecto, pero al probar en Mozilla sale el warning, pero colocando la función que me dices deja de aparecer el warning en Mozilla, Gracias por el aporte

Comment: @Jesús nada para eso estamos, como te indique eso funciona para todos los navegadores, ya que funciona de lado del servidor y lo que hace es enviar las cabeceras todas a la vez y así no te dice que no puede enviar las cabeceras si ya han sido enviadas, un saludo