# ¿Cannot modify header?

Tags: php

¿Como puedo solucionar esto?, subi por primera vez mi pagina web y me aparece los siguientes mensajes de errores al ver el sitio. Claro que este error no se representa de manera local, por lo que estaré omitiendo alguna regla importante quizas al subirlo a algún dominio...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    !DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <?php
            include 'config.inc.php';
            $db=new Conect_MySql();
                $sql = "select*from book where id=".$_GET['id'];
                $query = $db->execute($sql);
                if($datos=$db->fetch_row($query)){
                    if($datos['file']==""){?>
            <p>NO tiene archivos</p>
                    <?php }else{
   header('Content-type: application/pdf');
                        readfile('archivos/'.$datos['file']);
                    }
                } 
            ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: es un warning, localmente seguramente están desactivados fijate https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/32706/81450 de mover todo lo que envíe cabeceras al inicio del archivo. el warning dice textualmente: "no puedo enviar cabeceras ( `header('Content-type: application/pdf');` ) por que ya salió algo antes ( `<!DOCTYPE html><html>` ... ) "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te está ocurriendo es que realizas un envio de cabeceras **despues** de imprimir algo en pantalla, y eso no está permitido (basicamente hablando).

Lo que tienes que hacer es esto:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

Es decir, el envio de cabeceras se debe poner **siempre** antes de "cualquier cosa" que pueda ser impresa en pantalla. Esto por ejemplo también te soltaría el mismo error:

```
<?php
echo 'hola';
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
...
```